# Connect gdb from Perl Script

Tags: perl, gdb, perl-module

I am writing perl script which is getting core from Production. I have got core and need to 
run the gdb on these core file. Can anyone provide me info to connect gdb from perl script.

Comment: Are you asking how to use `system('gdb filename')`?, or how to manipulate the debugger from within Perl as well? (Try the Expect module, or Expect::Simple, in that case).

Comment: ya Meanwhile I found the http://search.cpan.org/~jezra/Devel-GDB-2.02/lib/Devel/GDB.pm package which connect the gdb. But my purpose is to connect gdb than run core corefile and whre command into gdb and save the console output into file.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone provide me info to connect gdb from perl script.

You *don't* want to do that.

What you want to do instead, is figure out why your `perl` is crashing with a core dump in production. To do that, run

```
gdb /path/to/perl /path/to/core
```

on the production machine, then issue `where` command.